# Will Quantal Quetzal fit on a standard 700MB CD?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.10

I am installing Ubuntu Quantal Quetzal Desktop edition on a PC, and I am making an installation CD. I noticed that the download for the ISO image for Quantal Quetzal is 753MB.

A standard CD can only fit 700MB of data. Should I write the ISO to say a DVD instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use a DVD. The (approximate) free space on a CD is 700MB, so you won'te be able to burn that iso on a simple CD.